# php preg_replace base on index match

Tags: preg-replace

I have string that contain 2 a tags.I want to replace one of them to another string. I have the code like:

```
$pattern = "/<a\s+href=\"(http|https)\:\/\/[^\"]+\">/";
$content = "I have a link <a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com/\">link text </a> and I have another link <a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">Google</a>";
$content = preg_replace($pattern, "<a title='title' href=' '>", $content);
    echo $content;
```

The code above will add title attribute for both a tags. However,I want to only add the title attribute and remove href value when a tag have value is "google.". Is there any way to do that?